# React Unable to access props using map

Tags: reactjs

[image: Screenshot of TrackList props]

So I have a TrackList component with props.tracks which is an array of objects, yet when I try and pass this to a Track component using:

```
{this.props.tracks.map(track => {
  return <Track track={track} key={track.id}/>
})}
```

I get a TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

If they are undefined then why are they showing in the TrackList component?

If hard coded the tracks into TrackList then not a problem I can access them using .map()

Comment: can you add the code for TrackList component please

Comment: No need @Jesus Erwin Suarez nailed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
{this.props.tracks && 

    {this.props.tracks.map(track => {
      return <Track track={track} key={track.id}/>
    })}
}
```

Comment: LEGEND, any chance of an explanation why the addition is needed?

Comment: @joelpeyton Probably because the data isn't in redux at the time the component is first rendered but then is fetched async and is present later when you go look at the redux store. If you used a debugger to catch the exception or added a breakpoint, you should be able to see it in action.

Comment: Conditional rendering - only render map if the this.props.tracks has content

Answer (score 3):

The provided property `tracks` is `undefined` or `null`. To prevent errors in this case you have several options

1. Use defaultProps

```js
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
 ...
}

YourComponent.defaultProps {
   tracks: [],
}
```

2. Conditional rendering

```js
{this.props.tracks && this.props.tracks.map(
    ...
 )}
```

3. Set default value

```js
{(this.props.tracks || []).map(
   ...
)}
```

The last option is probably the least useful option because the `tracks` property will be undefined at all other places.

Answer (score 1):

If tracks are loaded in via an API, there might be a delay between when the component mounted and when the prop is available. Another option would be to set the default value of the tracks prop to an empty array. This would prevent the error from showing while the data is loading.

```
YourComponent.defaultProps = {
  tracks: []
};
```

[React default props](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#default-prop-values)